# Printing equation and intermediate calculation steps automatically

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there's a relatively simple way to print a variable, along with the intermediate steps used in calculating the value of that variable. For example, say I had the following code:

`a = 5 (input)`

`b = 10 (input)`

`c = 2 * b`

`d = b * c`

I'm trying to find a straightforward way to print the following without hardcoding a f string:

`c = 2 * b = 2 * 10 = 20`

`d = b * c = 10 * 20 = 200`

The goal is to print equations in this manner, so that the program's output can be easily checked and I want to be sure that the output matches the equations the program is actually evaluating. There are many equations that I need to output in this manner and doing this with a f strings doesn't seem very pythonic and would introduce some possibility for error. I've seen that there are some symbolic math packages available, but I'm not trying to go that route, as implementing them would complicate other aspects of the program.

Comment: I don't follow your requirement at all. What is `a = b * c = 5 * 10 = 50` useful for? It doesn't check the output, it simply lists the input (incorrectly, because the assignments get messed up)... that you programmatically wrote yourself

Comment: Sorry if the original post was unclear. I've edited it to illustrate the problem better

Comment: Perhaps I meant "motivation" rather than "requirement". The steps that the computer takes are documented perfectly, 100%, by the code itself. The output you're looking for does not, because it doesn't show the assignments in the correct order. If you want to be sure that the computer handles your logic correctly, then you'd normally have unit tests with input values and a check to ensure that it gives the expected output

Comment: The motivation is to create a report for the user, not for checking the code myself

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the variable names with their values and then `eval` in order to evaluate the resulting expression:

```
import re

def print_and_eval(equation, variables):
    target, expr = equation.split('=')
    literal = re.sub('[a-z]', lambda m: str(variables[m.group(0)]), expr.strip())
    result = eval(literal, {'__builtins__': {}}, None)
    print(f'{equation} = {literal} = {result}')
    variables[target.strip()] = result
    return variables
```

Example usage:

```
variables = print_and_eval('a = b * c', {'b': 5, 'c': 10})
```

Answer (score 0):

More compact code, but similar idea to @a_guest's:

```
def check_compute(x,y,operation):
    print(f'{x} {operation} {y} = { eval(str(x) + operation + str(y))}')
    return eval(str(x) + operation + str(y))

r = check_compute(2,3,'+')
2 + 3 = 5
r
5
```